# 1D signal to 2D spectrogram

Tags: spectrogram, stft

I struggling at transforming a 1D breathing signal into 2D spectrograms,
power spectral density as a function of time and frequency.
Does anyone have an idea about that?

Comment: Welcome, please read [ask]. At that moment it is unclear what exactly your problem is, which language you are using, etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working in the MATLAB environment, the STFT of a 1D signal can be obtained by using the Spectrogram() command. [Refer here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html)

And as for PSD, you can use the FFT to obtain the same. Refer [here](https://in.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/power-spectral-density-estimates-using-fft.html)